# Ctrl-J behaviour is different on two different macs

Tags: keyboard

I have two MacBooks, MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020, big sur 11.5.2) and MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019, big sur 11.4).

The pro does nothing when I press ctrl-j, this is the behaviour I want, as I use ctrl-j in tmux. My air, however, seems to treat ctrl-j as an enter key, meaning that I can't use tmux without changing the config that I'm used to, which I'm not willing to do.

How can I make my air behave like my pro?

Comment: Do you have any special key bindings configured? You can get a list with `hidutil property --get "UserKeyMapping"`

Comment: Ctrl-J **is** a newline (literally an LF character).  It's your Mac that does nothing with it that is the suspect machine.

Comment: @apoptosis it doesn't look like it, it's returning (null)

Comment: @MarcWilson yeah, I had read that, but my previous MacBook pro (2016) also didn't have the behaviour. At least, I could use the ctrl-J keybinding inside of tmux without a problem. My air is the first time that this has been a problem

Comment: I had the same problem, how did you solve it?

Comment: or maybe you can try `stty -inlcr`